# POST method AFNetworking response not complete

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, afnetworking

I want to send `NSDictionary` data with `AFNetworking` `POST` method and get result from server.
this my `NSDictionary` :

```
{
    "category_id" = "-1";
    "city_id" = "-1";
    "degree_id" = "-1";
    "experience_id" = "-1";
    industries =     (
                {
            id = 2;
        },
                {
            id = 4;
        },
                {
            id = 3;
        }
    );
    "position_id" = "-1";
    "salary_id" = "-1";
    skills =     (
                {
            aa = id;
        },
                {
            aa = asdasda;
        }
    );
    "type_id" = "-1";
}
```

when send this NSDictionary my server receive my data like this :

```
{
    "category_id" = "-1";
    "city_id" = "-1";
    "degree_id" = "-1";
    "experience_id" = "-1";
    industries =     (
        2,
        4,
        3
    );
    "position_id" = "-1";
    "salary_id" = "-1";
    skills =     (
        id,
        asdasda
    );
    "type_id" = "-1";
}
```

I'm so confused from this !!!

industries & skills are array of dictionary in my NSDictionary but when server to receive don't show key and only show value in array!!!

please guide me about that.

this is my `POST` method :

```
self.params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [self.params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.object.jobCategory integerValue]] forKey:@"category_id"];
    [self.params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.object.jobCity integerValue]] forKey:@"city_id"];
    [self.params setObject:self.object.industry forKey:@"industries"];
    [self.params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.object.educationDegree integerValue]] forKey:@"degree_id"];
    [self.params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.object.experience integerValue]] forKey:@"experience_id"];
    [self.params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.object.jobType integerValue]] forKey:@"type_id"];
    [self.params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.object.jobSalary integerValue]] forKey:@"salary_id"];
    [self.params setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.object.jobPosition integerValue]] forKey:@"position_id"];


    [self.params setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:@"skills"];
    [[self.params objectForKey:@"skills"] addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id",@"aa", nil]];
    [[self.params objectForKey:@"skills"] addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"asdasda",@"aa", nil]];
    //NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    //NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.params);
    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@" , [PublicMethods getStrings:@"url"],[PublicMethods getStrings:@"searchJob"]];
    [self.network callPOSTWebServiceWithPath:path AndWithParameters:self.params withCallback:^(NSDictionary *result)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",result);
         if ([[result objectForKey:@"result"]boolValue])
         {
             NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);
         }
         else
         {
             //error accured
         }

     }];
```

Comment: The second log you show is `self.params`? Did you log `self.object.industry` to check if it's correct? What's the log `[self.params objectForKey:@"skills"]`? I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: @Larme my friend when I log [self.params objectForKey:@"skills"] display me this : skills =     (
                {
            aa = id;
        },
                {
            aa = asdasda;
        }
    )

Answer (score 0):

It is a very easy issue.
You send a string data in which includes NSDictionary nested NSArray.
But you send it to the server.
Your code of industries and skills which there is the same key in the array. 
So when it sent to the server, and then returned value without key.That's correct.

Wanna see your returned value with key.Just change your id likes id1, id2, id3. As to it ,the variable of aa is just like that.

Finally , you'll see the key with value be returned .
Good luck！

Comment: Try to do this
industries =     (
                {
            "id" = "2"
        },
                {
            "id" = "4"
        },
                {
           " id" = "3"
        }
    )